# Java code that removes items from a text list

Tags: java, arrays, parallel-processing

this is my current code and I am having troubles removing the name and the net and gross information included with the name.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
public static int removeName(String[] nameArray,
        int[] grossArray, int[] netArray, int counter) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    int nameSearch;

    System.out.println("Please enter the name you would like to remove.");

    name = keyboard.nextLine();
    nameSearch = searchArray(nameArray, name);

    if (nameSearch != -1) {
        nameArray[nameSearch] = name;

        counter--;
    } else {
        System.out.println("That name is not on the list");
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Code runs and gives no errors.  When the code runs it just edits the name I type in depending on the case format I use (uppercase/lowercase).  I need this code to remove the name and the information associated with it.  When removing I also need the list to move up so if I delete Bob for example and Jen is below Bob Jen takes Bob's place since he is deleted. I am not allowed to use array lists.

Comment: Does your code run? What error do you get? What does the code do when it runs? What do you want it to do? You have to make sure to address all of these questions for us to be able to help you...otherwise, we don't really know what you're even asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (nameSearch != -1) {
    nameArray[nameSearch] = name;

    counter--;
} else {
    System.out.println("That name is not on the list");
}
return counter;
```

Why are you setting nameArray[nameSearch] to name? Don't you want to remove what's in nameArray[nameSearch]?

If that's what you want to do you could temporarily convert nameArray into an ArrayList and remove what's at the index of nameSearch. Something like this:

```
List<String> nameArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(nameArray));
nameArrayList.remove(nameSearch);
nameArray = nameArrayList.toArray();
```

If you do this you might as well consider keeping nameArray as an arrayList throughout your function.

Comment: I just posted this, but I am not allowed to use an array list.  Sorry for the time you put in to this.